# How Can I generate specific table from XML in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have a xml document. I want to generate table with this xml.
Here is my xml data

```
Declare @Result XML
SET @Result='
<General>
  <Customer>
    <model_year>2011</model_year>
    <vehicle_id>1</vehicle_id>
    <customer_requests>
      <request>
        <definition>I want to new car tyre</definition>
      </request>
      <request>
        <definition>I want to new headlight</definition>
      </request>
    </customer_requests>
    <mileage>34000</mileage>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <model_year>2012</model_year>
    <vehicle_id>2</vehicle_id>
    <customer_requests>
      <request>
        <definition>I want to general maintenance</definition>
      </request>
    </customer_requests>
    <mileage>35000</mileage>
  </Customer>
</General>
'
```

This is sample output

| model_year | vehicle_id | request | mileage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | 1 | I want to new car tyre,I want to new headlight | 34000 |
| 2012 | 2 | I want to general maintenance | 35000 |

How can I generate table from XML data like sample output with tsql?

Comment: I suggest if you *do* want to get the data from the XML you normalise it. *Never* have delimited data in your database. As for how to read it, have a look at XQuery. There are plenty of resources on how to consume XML in SQL Server, including the documentation. What about the articles/tutorials/documentation didn't you understand? Why didn't the attempts you made work, and what were they?

Comment: @Larnu How can I normalize it? Have you got a resource for this?

Comment: *"How can I normalize it?"* By not returning delimited data in your expected results, as I said.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It is using XQuery's FLWOR expression to concatenate multiple `<definition>` tag values into one string.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @Result XML = 
N'<General>
  <Customer>
    <model_year>2011</model_year>
    <vehicle_id>1</vehicle_id>
    <customer_requests>
      <request>
        <definition>I want to new car tyre</definition>
      </request>
      <request>
        <definition>I want to new headlight</definition>
      </request>
    </customer_requests>
    <mileage>34000</mileage>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <model_year>2012</model_year>
    <vehicle_id>2</vehicle_id>
    <customer_requests>
      <request>
        <definition>I want to general maintenance</definition>
      </request>
    </customer_requests>
    <mileage>35000</mileage>
  </Customer>
</General>';

SELECT c.value('(model_year/text())[1]', 'CHAR(4)') AS model_year
    ,  c.value('(vehicle_id/text())[1]', 'INT') AS vehicle_id
    ,  c.query('for $x in customer_requests/request/definition
                return if ($x is (customer_requests/request[last()]/definition)[1]) then data($x)
                        else concat($x/text()[1], ",")')
        .value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS request
    ,  c.value('(mileage/text())[1]', 'INT') AS mileage
FROM @Result.nodes('/General/Customer') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+
| model_year | vehicle_id |                     request                     | mileage |
+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+
|       2011 |          1 | I want to new car tyre, I want to new headlight |   34000 |
|       2012 |          2 | I want to general maintenance                   |   35000 |
+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+
```